# Reusing same thread across the Postbacks in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

In web server code, One of the object is opening the socket connection to listen from another third party server. This socket connection is specific to individual users logged into our web server.

I want to run and retain the listener object in the individual thread, so that I can use same thread block to that particular user across the post-backs. We are planning for approximately 100 concurrent sessions on single web server.

Is it possible to implement this architecture, I understand that it is not the good practice to launch the long running threads in ASP.Net. I do not have other options because we are depending on third party servers we are using. How can I keep track of these threads and re-associate during the post-back

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.
Sunil

Answer (score 1):

You may do that only if you run a single pool (not many pools/web-garden)*

You can use a `static Dictionary<string, object>` to store a thread pointer (the object) connected with a string that is connected with the session id of the user.

When the user enter the page, you check if have a thread running, base on the session-id, using the static Dictionary, then if he has one you can get the thread, or else you make one new... and the rest is up to you.

Also make sure that the one pool is not automatic recycle.

This is a simple general idea. You need to implement the synchronization of the dictionary, the handle of the threads, and the connection with the session.

[*] If you have many pools, then the static Dictionary will be break on many threads, (the different pools), so you can not hold only one thread per user.

**If you have many pools.**
In this case you need a database to hold the results from the threads/connection you open. There you use the database that you connect the user id (if its registered), or the session id of the user, with the returning results from your asynchronous events, and you show to your user on the next view page.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The listener object is used to send the synchronous message through socket and also used to listen to the asynchronous events. The received messages have to be parsed and sent to the appropriate client browser.

Comment: @Sunil All of that can you handle it on the class/thread that you open. Later when the user see the page, any page, you can render the results. Hope this make sense.